# Sending SMS using AT commands via C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, at-command

I am using AT commands to send text message via C#.net. How to send a long message i.e. message more than 16o chars ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check out the AT commands documentation for this.

Comment: Check This Command AT+CMGS=<Mobile Number>enter<Message>ctrl+Z

Answer (score 2):

Its purely depends on the GSM/GPRS Modem, If the modem like SIM300 it supports 480 Character,where as Sim700,SIM900 version supports 160 character only as single message, though you text more than 160 character it send the SMS by part, Follow the link and get the details about C#.net AT command application.

Check the GSM/GPRS MODEM documentation.

http://www.activexperts.com/download?p1=ax004

Hope it helps.

Comment: my modem supports it. I have used this, logixmobile library and i was able to send long messages.

Comment: http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcorelib/help/index.asp?p=http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcorelib/help/source/Reference/SMSObject/Properties/longmessage.htm i think you find the answer here